# storing post->post_content in jquery variable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, variables

I am trying to store the post_content into a variable and then add that variable to the array.
but when getting the content if I have this:

```
<div class="col2 left">
 <!--COMMENT-->
</div>
<div class="col2 right">
 <!--COMMENT-->
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
     <li><!--IMAGE--></li>
  </ul>
```

when trying to store it, it gives me an error because of the line breaks.  I need to keep that format.

```
var estructuras = [];
<?php foreach ($est as $estr): ?>
var new_data_var = $('<?php echo $estr->post_content; ?>');
estructuras['<?php echo $estr->post_title; ?>'] = new_data_var;
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

EDIT:
Now using what was suggested, it is echoing into the body instead of holding in $jsData..

```
<?php
   $jsData = array();
   foreach ($est as $estr) {
      $jsData[$estr->post_title] = $estr->post_content;
   }
?>
var estructuras = <?php echo json_encode($jsData); ?>;
```

and for the var value I get this:

```
var estructuras = {"":null};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
<?php
$jsData = array();
foreach ($est as $estr) {
    $jsData[$estr->post_title] = $estr->post_content;
}
?>
var estructuras = <?php echo json_encode($jsData); ?>;
```